# Pandas - Expanding average session time

Tags: pandas, group-by, mean, timedelta

The following DF represents events received from users. Id of the user and the timestamp of the event:

```
    id           timestamp
0    1 2020-09-01 18:14:35
1    1 2020-09-01 18:14:39
2    1 2020-09-01 18:14:40
3    1 2020-09-01 02:09:22
4    1 2020-09-01 02:09:35
5    1 2020-09-01 02:09:53
6    1 2020-09-01 02:09:57
7    2 2020-09-01 18:14:35
8    2 2020-09-01 18:14:39
9    2 2020-09-01 18:14:40
10   2 2020-09-01 02:09:22
11   2 2020-09-01 02:09:35
12   2 2020-09-01 02:09:53
13   2 2020-09-01 02:09:57
```

I would like to get the average **expanding** session time. A session is defined as a sequence  of events that is terminated by more than 5 minutes break.

I've grouped the sessions like so:

```
df.groupby(['id', pd.Grouper(key="timestamp", freq='5min', origin='start')])
```

And got the right groups:

```
   id           timestamp
3   1 2020-09-01 02:09:22
4   1 2020-09-01 02:09:35
5   1 2020-09-01 02:09:53
6   1 2020-09-01 02:09:57
   id           timestamp
0   1 2020-09-01 18:14:35
1   1 2020-09-01 18:14:39
2   1 2020-09-01 18:14:40
    id           timestamp
10   2 2020-09-01 02:09:22
11   2 2020-09-01 02:09:35
12   2 2020-09-01 02:09:53
13   2 2020-09-01 02:09:57
   id           timestamp
7   2 2020-09-01 18:14:35
8   2 2020-09-01 18:14:39
9   2 2020-09-01 18:14:40
```

Now I would like to calculate the average session time in seconds per user at any given row, so the output is:

```
    id           timestamp  avg_session_time
0    1 2020-09-01 18:14:35  0 <-- first event
1    1 2020-09-01 18:14:39  4 <-- 2nd event after 4 seconds
2    1 2020-09-01 18:14:40  5 <-- 3rd event after 5 seconds
--- session end
3    1 2020-09-01 02:09:22  5 <-- first event of second session
4    1 2020-09-01 02:09:35  9 <-- 2nd event after 13 seconds (13 seconds in the 2nd session + 5 in first session divide by the number of sessions 2)
5    1 2020-09-01 02:09:53  18 <-- 3rd event after 31 seconds ((31 + 5) / 2 = 18)
6    1 2020-09-01 02:09:57  20 <-- 4th event after 35 seconds ((35 + 5) / 2 = 20)
---
7    2 2020-09-01 18:14:35  0
8    2 2020-09-01 18:14:39  4
9    2 2020-09-01 18:14:40  5
---
10   2 2020-09-01 02:09:22  5
11   2 2020-09-01 02:09:35  9
12   2 2020-09-01 02:09:53  18
13   2 2020-09-01 02:09:57  20
```

Any help would be awesome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#converting to datetimes
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

#grouping per 5Min and id
g = df.groupby(['id', pd.Grouper(key="timestamp", freq='5min', origin='start')])
#get first values per groups to new column
df['diff'] = g['timestamp'].transform('first')
#subtract by timestamp and convert timedeltas to seconds
df['diff'] = df['timestamp'].sub(df['diff']).dt.total_seconds()
#shifting per groups by id
df['new'] = df.groupby('id')['diff'].shift()
#get first value per groups, now shifted
df['new'] = g['new'].transform('first')
#replace 0 to misisng values and get average
df['last'] = df[['new','diff']].replace(0, np.nan).mean(axis=1).fillna(df['new'])

print (df)
    id           timestamp  diff  new  last
0    1 2020-09-01 18:14:35   0.0  0.0   0.0
1    1 2020-09-01 18:14:39   4.0  0.0   4.0
2    1 2020-09-01 18:14:40   5.0  0.0   5.0
3    1 2020-09-01 02:09:22   0.0  5.0   5.0
4    1 2020-09-01 02:09:35  13.0  5.0   9.0
5    1 2020-09-01 02:09:53  31.0  5.0  18.0
6    1 2020-09-01 02:09:57  35.0  5.0  20.0
7    2 2020-09-01 18:14:35   0.0  0.0   0.0
8    2 2020-09-01 18:14:39   4.0  0.0   4.0
9    2 2020-09-01 18:14:40   5.0  0.0   5.0
10   2 2020-09-01 02:09:22   0.0  5.0   5.0
11   2 2020-09-01 02:09:35  13.0  5.0   9.0
12   2 2020-09-01 02:09:53  31.0  5.0  18.0
13   2 2020-09-01 02:09:57  35.0  5.0  20.0
```

Comment: can you please have a look here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69796707/pandas-oversampling-ragged-sequential-data